# How configure Solr to only accept request by sending keypass/access-token

Tags: security, solr, access-token

Solr experts,

at the moment i am using a custom proxy script to only accept requests with the right keypass-parameter. Is it possible to configure solr for such a use case, so i do not need this proxy script?

for example: localhost/proxy/search?keypass=asdaefva&query=SEARCHPARAMETERS

best regards
Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent enough Solr version, you can [use Solr's built in support for Authentication and Authorization](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html). This also allows you to limit the collections and operations that a given key (i.e. user:pass) can access.

These are configured in a file named `security.json`, which is either store in Zookeeper (for SolrCloud), or locally on disk (using a local file in stand alone mode support was added later than the original support for using it in cluster mode).

```
{
  "authentication":{
    "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials":{
      "solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="
    }
  },
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "permissions":[
      {
        "name":"security-edit", 
        "role":"admin"
      }
    ],
    "user-role":{
      "solr":"admin"
    }
  }
```

}
}

> When running Solr in standalone mode, you need to create the `security.json` file and put it in the `$SOLR_HOME` directory for your installation (this is the same place you have located `solr.xml` and is usually `server/solr`).